# Joining a query and a table and getting mistake?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT b.adi, b.soyadi
FROM besteci b, sarki s
WHERE b.bestecino = (
SELECT s.bestecino FROM sarki s
WHERE s.uzunluk > 180 
EXCEPT  
SELECT s.bestecino FROM sarki s
WHERE s.turu = 'halk');
```

I have to use natural join to join one table and a query result so i write it as a subquery. But i'm getting that "Subquery returns more than 1 row" mistake" error. how can i solve it?  (i can use not exists instead except)
edit: question is 
List the names and surnames of composers who have composed a song (or songs) longer than 180 seconds, but have not composed a song of the type "Folk".

Comment: mysql does not have EXCEPT (mssql/sqlserver does) is this tagged correctly or are you trying to convert from sqlserver to mysql?

Comment: Explain the logic that you want to implement.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: 'List the names and surnames of composers' - why is sarki s in the from clause since you don't use it?

Comment: Since when MySQL has `EXCEPT`?

Comment: `=` expects 1 value.  Yours return multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because of this where clause :

```
WHERE b.bestecino = (
    SELECT
        s.bestecino 
    FROM 
        sarki s
    WHERE 
        s.uzunluk > 180 
    EXCEPT  
    SELECT
        s.bestecino 
    FROM 
        sarki s
    WHERE 
        s.turu = 'halk'
);
```

This can return more than one row depending on the data in the table, you should either Limit the results set to a single record using TOP(1) or LIMIT - depending on what type of database youre using, or you can change the WHERE to an IN(..) rather than an = (...)

Comment: yes it return more than 1 row. but i need all values

Comment: @melisa - Then you should change the where clause, rather than using "WHERE  b.bestecino =" you should use an IN - "WHERE b.bestecino IN (...